# Dnlib - как найти и изменить boolean операнд?

Tags: c#, dnlib

Подскажите как можно найти `bool` операнд через библиотеку dnlib
Через поиск смог найти

> System.Boolean Filename.folder.classname::methodbl
> // Filename - имя программы
> // folder - директория в которой лежат классы
> // classname - имя класса где записаны переменные
> // methodbl - переменная типа `bool` со значением `false`

В коде записано так:

```
public static bool methodbl = false;
```

Заменять пробую так:

```
public static void GetAllMethodsFromModule(ModuleDefMD module)
{
  foreach (TypeDef type in module.GetTypes().Where(t => t.HasMethods))
  {
     foreach (var method in type.Methods.Where(m => m.HasBody))
     {
       IList<Instruction> instr = method.Body.Instructions;
       for (int i = 0; i < instr.Count; i++)
       {
         if (instr[i].OpCode == OpCodes.Ldstr)
         {
           if (instr[i].Operand.ToString().Contains("DefaultText"))
           {
             instr[i].Operand = "NewText";
           }            
         }
        if (instr[i].OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0)
        {
           try
           {
             if (instr[i].Operand.ToString().Contains("System.Boolean Filename.folder.classname::methodbl"))
             {
               instr[i].Operand = OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1;
             }
           }
           catch { }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: это не такая тривиальная задача, т.к. в `IL` нет отдельного типа для `bool`, он представляется как `int`, `ldc.i4.1` = 1 = true, `ldc.i4.0` = 0 = false, поэтому вы можете случайно заменить что-то не то. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387010/ilgenerator-how-to-add-boolean-to-the-stack

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, Как тогда правильно найти эту инструкцию в определённом классе  и изменить её?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно заменять код не в методе, а в статическом конструкторе (`cctor`), т.к. у вас создается статическое поле:

```
public static bool methodbl = false;
```

Например, заменить все `false` на `true`:

```
var module = ModuleDefMD.Load(/* ... */);
var type = module.Types.First(/* ... */);
var cctor = type.FindStaticConstructor();
var instructions = cctor.Body.Instructions;

for (var i = 0; i < instructions.Count; i++)
{
    var instruction = instructions[i];

    if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0) // check for false
    {
        instruction.OpCode = OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1;
    }
}
```

В вашем случает это не работает, т.к. в методе находится загрузка значение поля на стек, а это `ldsfld` инструкция.

UPD: для того чтобы обновить конкретное поле, проверять немного больше условий, инициализация поля компилируется в:

```
ldc.i4.0
stsfld       bool xxx.Program::methodbl
```

то, можно попытаться проверять `stsfld` и имя поля, а заменять прошлую команду (+ возможно нужно будет учесть какие-то доп. случаи), например:

```
if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Stsfld &&
    instruction.Operand is FieldDef fieldDef &&
    fieldDef.Name == "methodbl") 
{
    instructions[i - 1].OpCode = OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1;
}
```

Также стоит учитывать и тот кейс, когда у вас `bool` будет инициализированная значением по умолчанию, т.е. `false`, тогда статический конструктор не будет создаваться компиляторам, и вам нужно будет его создать руками.

Comment: Мне не нужно заменять все `false` на `true` только в определённом месте.

Comment: @ZidoX обновил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень выручили)