# Dnlib - как найти и изменить byte[] array?

Tags: c#, dnlib

Подскажите как изменить байты в коде другого приложения?
Как в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196510/dnlib-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-boolean-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4) примере, только за место `bool` нужно заменить `byte[] array`
В другом приложение есть код:

```
public static class Test
{
   public static byte[] ArrMyBytes = new byte[]
   {
      //"0x"
      0x12D
   };
}
```

Мне нужно заменить `0x12D` на свои байты, как это можно реализовать?
И ещё вопросик можно ли найти комментарии через `dnlib` и их тоже менять?

---

```
public static void GetAllMethodsFromModule(ModuleDefMD module)
{
  foreach (TypeDef type in module.GetTypes().Where(t => t.HasMethods))
  {
     foreach (var method in type.Methods.Where(m => m.HasBody))
     {
       IList<Instruction> instr = method.Body.Instructions;
       for (int i = 0; i < instr.Count; i++)
       {
         // Ldstr - это string'овые 
         if (instr[i].OpCode == OpCodes.Ldstr)
         {
           if (instr[i].Operand.ToString().Contains("DefaultText"))
           {
             instr[i].Operand = "NewText";
           }            
         }
        // Ldc_I4_0 - false | Ldc_I4_1 - true  (булевы переменные )
        if (instr[i].OpCode == OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0)
        {
           try
           {
             if (instr[i].Operand.ToString().Contains("System.Boolean Filename.folder.classname::methodbl"))
             {
               instr[i].Operand = OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1;
             }
           }
           catch { }
         }
         //  if (instr[i].OpCode == OpCodes. Что здесь для поиска byte[] array ??
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ViRb3/dnEditor

Comment: @aepot, Да мне бы действующий пример, а то в исходниках ковыряться, толком ничего не понятно..

Comment: Чем тот пример не  действующий? ) И как вы представляете пример без исходников?

Comment: @aepot, Тот пример действующий только для замены булевых и стринговых значений. А вот как мне найти и заменить байты я не знаю, там так не получается. Исходники? Куда залить на яндекс диск?

Comment: dnlib оперирует с IL (и PE headers), а они не содержат комментарии к коду, поэтому их не возможно поменять в exe/dll, только в коде, например, при помощи анализаторов